# create page structure in Strapi headless CMS

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, strapi, next.js13

maybe there is someone who has experience to work with ( Strapi Headless CMS ) .

We need to implement page structures . for example , we need to give admin permission to create page structures on Strapi level ( different order of components , some additional components per page , publish/not publish ... ).

I am wondering , if someone did same before . and I will be happy if you will share some difficulties or some good practices to approach same .

Best Regards .